# Autovalidate of TextFormField is deprecated in Flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, dart

'autovalidate' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use autoValidateMode parameter which provide more specific behaviour related to auto validation. This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0..
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e24jK.png)

Comment: Can you specify what is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### autovalidate is replaced by autovalidateMode

Auto validation is deprecated and replaced by an enum. So you should migrate to the new version.

All you need to do is replace **autovalidate: true** with   **autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always**

### The different supported modes are

1. AutovalidateMode.always
2. AutovalidateMode.disabled
3. AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction

### Example:

Code before migration:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField(
      autovalidate: true,
      builder: (FormFieldState state) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Code after migration:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      builder: (FormFieldState state) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**autovalidate** is deprecated from Flutter v1.19

Replace **autovalidate** with **autovalidateMode**.

**autovalidateMode** can have one of the below 3 values:

1. **autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled**:
   No auto validation will occur.
2. **autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always**:
   Used to auto-validate FormField even without user interaction.
3. **autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction**:
   Used to auto-validate FormField only after each user interaction.

I suggest try all the above values one by one and use the one that fulfills ur requirement.

Comment: Has anyone used `Autovalidate.disabled` ? It's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

autovalidate has been depreciated, now you need to use autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always
checkout the flutter documentation for it via:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/form-field-autovalidation-api